# Why does bash.exe run twice when using --login?

Tags: bash, windows, cygwin

When running cygwin, the shortcut I have uses the following:

```
C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe --login -i
```

What is unclear to me is why bash.exe executes twice. I see two processes running in task manager. If I put an echo statement `echo .Bashrc file has been processed` at the bottom of my `.bashrc` file I will see that echo output appear twice in the console window.

[image]

What is it about `bash.exe --login` that causes the process to run twice?  (is this expected behavior?)

Comment: You may want to include the contents of your `.bash_profile` (or `.profile`) file as well as `.bashrc` in the question. I'm guessing that one of them is starting a new `bash` process for some reason.

Comment: oh cripes.. good call. I didn't look in the .bash_profile. *smacks forhead* Sure enough I have this :  `[[ -z $SSH_AGENT_PID && -z $DISPLAY ]] && exec -l ssh-agent $SHELL -c "bash --login"`.  `.bash_profile` must only get called when `--login` is used?

Comment: That's a correct understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `bash` shell that is a login shell will source `~/.bash_profile`.

The `~/.bash_profile` file on Marcel's Cygwin system contained the line

```
[[ -z $SSH_AGENT_PID && -z $DISPLAY ]] && exec -l ssh-agent $SHELL -c "bash --login"
```

This will start `ssh-agent` if no such agent is running in the current shell environment and if there's no X11 display available. The SSH agent will start two new `bash` shells, a non-interactive shell and a login shell (the login shell will skip over the above line since it will have `$SSH_AGENT_PID` set). The SSH agent replaces the shell it's starting from by virtue of being started with `exec`.

The two `bash` processes that may be seen are

1. The one started by `ssh-agent` (this is `$SHELL -c`), and
2. The one started by the `$SHELL -c`, invoking `bash --login`.

---

To me, it looks like the line could be simplified down into

```
[[ -z $SSH_AGENT_PID && -z $DISPLAY ]] && exec -l ssh-agent bash --login
```

That would get rid of the extra shell that `ssh-agent` uses just for running `bash --login`.

Comment: minor correction; my .bash_profile contains the ssh agent line. I don't actually have a .bash_login.

Comment: I found another post that provides an even better way to launch the ssh-agent here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880024/start-ssh-agent-on-login

Comment: @MarcelWilson Sorry for the typo, it was in the middle of the night.

Answer (score -1):

@Kusalananda pointed out that `--login` triggers .bash_profile to be called.  My .bash_profile had the following line

```
[[ -z $SSH_AGENT_PID && -z $DISPLAY ]] && exec -l ssh-agent $SHELL -c "bash --login"
```

thus a second bash was being opened everytime.

Comment: It's slightly more complicated than that :-) The shell you start stops existing at the `exec` and is replaced by `ssh-agent`. The agent starts `$SHELL` (`bash`) and then that `bash` issues the `bash --login` command.

Comment: Right, but that doesn't happen if I don't use `--login`, thus `--login` is the triggering effect as to why I would see two bash processes, no?

Comment: Correct again. Unless `~/.bash_profile` is sourced by `~/.bashrc`, it won't be read by a non-login `bash`.